# C# LINQ-like cast method for C++ std::vector?

Tags: c#, c++, linq, casting

Lets say I have got `std::vector<double> list` which I would like to be `std::vector<int> list`

In C# I would do something like this: `list.Cast<int>()`. How would I do that in C++?

Is there a LINQ-like cast method for C++ std::vector?

Comment: The Linq namespace must be accessible in C++ too. I'm not sure it can handle extension methods. But you must be able to call it with Enumerable.Cast<int>(list); it's a simple static method call.

Comment: `std::vector<int> list2(list.begin(), list.end());`

Comment: What is the actual problem? LINQ exists for both C# and C++. Sources: https://github.com/isndev/qb-linq#linq and https://github.com/mrange/cpplinq#cpplinq---linq-like-list-manipulations-for-c11